# Does "freed hostage" make sense?

Tags: meaning

> Freed Israeli hostage Mia Schem in first interview since her release
> from Hamas captivity in Gaza​

"Hostage" "means person seized or held as security for the fulfilment of a condition."

"Free" means "release from confinement or slavery."

Is "freed hostage" contradictory? Or Does it make sense?

Comment: What do you think would be a rational way for expressing this concept? You found the sentence in an online article, is the article aimed at English speakers? Would a journalist write something nonsensical. OK; writers, authors, we all make mistakes from time to time but you should spend your energy checking whether a phrase is commonly found in dictionaries or online before asking a question on ELL.

Comment: ["freed hostage"](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=594761302&sxsrf=AM9HkKknoEb9WfZP6CpgG7JT4hH5TfD9zQ:1704038996291&q=%22freed+hostage%22&tbm=nws&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9o7r4h7qDAxUbhf0HHUHiC_gQ0pQJegQICRAB&biw=1137&bih=630&dpr=2.5)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Then, "freed hostage" is a semantical error?

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much.

Comment: *"Then, "freed hostage" is a semantical error?"* Where did I say that?! I believe too many users give answers in comments instead of helping learners reach the answer using their own wits. Give a man a fish and he'll eat for one day. Teach a man to plant potatoes and how to fish and he'll never be hungry… (not a faithful reproduction of the original proverb but you should get the idea)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ***freed hostages*** (like [***retired workers***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+retired+worker%22) and [***divorced husbands***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+divorced+husband%22)) are unexceptional in English.

Comment: I suppose an extinguished fire would cause a mental meltdown?

Answer (score 4):

It's perfectly understandable.  She was a hostage until she was freed.  Only the most ridiculous pedant would insist on "freed former hostage".

Comment: Hysterical image.